# Алгоритм поиска палиндрома

Tags: java, алгоритм

Как написать алгоритм "который ищет полиндроми и подсчитывает их количество после чего записывает в файл txt" ?

Задали это сделать алгоритмично.(

Мой код

```
public class zad2Ver3 {

private static String pathToFile = "/Users/mk/Desktop/palindromy.txt";
private static String newPathToFile = "/Users/mk/Desktop/newPalindrom.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    readTXT();
}

private static void readTXT() throws Exception {
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            strList.add(line);
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) {
            String str = strList.get(i);
            char[] chr = new char[str.toCharArray().length];
            if (wykladPalindrom(chr) == true) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);
            }


        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File does not exist");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("File with path " + pathToFile + " not found");
    }
}


public static boolean wykladPalindrom(char str[]) {
    int i, j;
    j = str.length;
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        if (str[i] != str[j - 1 - i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Вы это запускали?

Answer (score 6):

Вот вам еще 2 варианта, но начинайте делать задания самостоятельно. Если вы сдаетесь на таких тривиальных задачах, учитывая, что у вас есть преподаватель, который отвечает на любые вопросы и еще что-то предварительно объясняет, имея огромное количество материала в инете (включая уже решенные аналогичные задачи), то что будет в реальной разработке...

```
public static boolean isPslindrom1(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString().equals(str);
}

public static boolean isPslindrom2(String str) {        
    char[] temp = new char[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) temp[str.length() - i - 1] = str.charAt(i);
    return new String (temp).equals(str);
}
```

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен. Жаль только мой препод ведет сейчас занятия онлайн через чат((( и только дает задания.

Comment: @Hotosho это всего лишь незначительные временные трудности... поверьте, не только вы столкнулись с некоторыми проблемами дистанционной работы)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static boolean isPalindrom(char str[]) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0, j = str.length - 1; str[i] == str[j] && i < j; i++, j--);
  return i >= j;
}

if (wykladPalindrom(str.toCharArray())) {
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за помощь, я нашел ошибку в своем коде... почему не он не работал.
Теперь работает) НО я знаю что мой способ самый не верный)

```
package algo4;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Zadanie2Polindrom {

    private static String pathToFile = "/Users/mk/Desktop/palindromy.txt";
    private static String newPathToFile = "/Users/mk/Desktop/newPalindrom.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        readTXT();
    }

    private static void readTXT() throws Exception {
        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                strList.add(line);
            }

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) {
                String str = strList.get(i);
                char[] chr = new char[str.length()];
                for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                    chr[j] = str.charAt(j);
                }
                if (wykladPalindrom(chr) == true) {
                    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newPathToFile, true))) {
                        bw.write(str + "\n");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println(newPathToFile + " Can't write to file");
                    }
                    count++;

                }

            }
            System.out.println(count);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File does not exist");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File with path " + pathToFile + " not found");
        }
    }


    public static boolean wykladPalindrom(char str[]) {
        int i, j;
        j = str.length;
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            if (str[i] != str[j - 1 - i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```